# Missing Offline and Themes in Google Apps Mail

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

On my mail page for my Google Apps hosted domain, in the settings view, the Offline and Themes tabs are missing.  They are there on my me@gmail.com account, and on other people's hosted domains.  Any ideas why I'm special and don't have these options?

Addendum:
I just enabled Pre-Release features, and I cleared my cache and cookies.  No change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed from US English to UK English same time I switched "Pre-release features on".  This disabled the Next Generation Control Panel, (US only option), and once I went back to Standard Control Panel, it all works.  Yay, kudos to @ceejayoz for the pointer.

Comment: How long did you need to wait before it showed up?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have "Enable pre-release features" turned on in the domain control panel? Google holds back some features from Apps until they're deemed stable enough, unless you check that box.

Comment: Good point. Also, some options depend on your language; English might show more than some localised version.

Comment: My language is English.  Just 'cos I'm from SA doesn't mean I have to speak Sesotho or isiZulu :-)